# Service not in scope from within an Angular event handler

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I've decided to learn Angular.js after having learned JavaScript and jQuery and am finding the going a bit rough.  Here's my code.

index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Resolute</title>
        <script src="js/angular 1.3.0-beta9/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="resoluteApp">
        <form novalidation ng-controller="resoluteCtrl" ng-submit="submit()">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.js:

```
var app = angular.module('resoluteApp', []);

app.service('resoluteService', function myService() {
    this.bar = function() { return 'resolute'; };
});

app.controller('resoluteCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.submit = function() {
            alert(resoluteService.bar());  // resoluteService is undefined here
        };
    });
```

I would like to be able to call the function `bar()` defined in the service `resoluteService` from within the `ng-submit` event handler `$scope.submit()`.  Upon pressing the Submit button, I get the following error (Chrome 35.0.1916.153) in the console:

```
ReferenceError: resoluteService is not defined
    at Scope.$scope.submit (http://localhost:8383/resolute/js/index.js:9:19)
    at http://localhost:8383/resolute/js/angular%201.3.0-beta9/angular.js:10797:21
    at http://localhost:8383/resolute/js/angular%201.3.0-beta9/angular.js:19791:17
    at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:8383/resolute/js/angular%201.3.0-beta9/angular.js:12699:28)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:8383/resolute/js/angular%201.3.0-beta9/angular.js:12797:23)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8383/resolute/js/angular%201.3.0-beta9/angular.js:19790:21)
    at http://localhost:8383/resolute/js/angular%201.3.0-beta9/angular.js:2860:10
    at forEach (http://localhost:8383/resolute/js/angular%201.3.0-beta9/angular.js:327:20)
    at HTMLFormElement.eventHandler (http://localhost:8383/resolute/js/angular%201.3.0-beta9/angular.js:2859:5)
```

As I'm still trying to get my head wrapped around the Angular way of doing things, I am not sure how to direct either `resoluteService` or the function `bar` within it to be in scope of `$scope.submit`.  It may be I'm thinking about it in entirely the wrong way, or it may just be something simple I'm missing.  Any thoughts as to how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject the service in to controller ,

```
app.controller('resoluteCtrl', function($scope,resoluteService) {

}
```

Comment: I knew it would be something simple... works like a charm.  Thanks.